# Counting values in columns including values not present

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
3  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
4  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
```

I want to count on every column the number of 0s,1s and 2s.
I thought using, `unique` or `table` on each column, but the problem is that not every column has the values that I want to count. For instance, column 1, is the only one that has a `1` on it.

I guess I could do a for loop, but was thinking that there has to be a better way to do it?

Comment: E.g. `lapply( df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=1:3)) )`?

Comment: @lukeA Very nice, but I think one should use `levels=0:2` in this case.

Comment: @RHertel Oops, you're right. Thx. :)

Comment: You guys are genius!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `table` after `stack`ing the data

```
table(stack(df))
```

```
      ind
values V1 V10 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
     0  2   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
     1  1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     2  2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Comment: I just noticed that the order of the variables will change! Easy to fix but I thing it is still worth pointing out

Comment: @Javier2013 You can use `melt` from `reshape2` instead of `stack` for order preserving default.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(df1))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#0  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
#1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
```